# Can I deploy Java/JSP/Struts 2 Web application on Sharepoint portal of Office 365

Tags: java, jsp, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, hosting

I would really appreciate if someone could educate me on if I can host my JAVA/JSP/Strtus based web application in Sharepoint.

My client wanted me to host an application from them on their SharePoint Portal.

My application uses MySQL 5.5 for storage of data.

I regularly keep deploying web applications on Linux based Servers with Apache Tomcat - but have no idea and 0% experience on Sharepoint.

Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using archaic ugly java when the target environment supports modern, beautiful C#?

Comment: Because, I am well versed only with Java. Java, though is not as beautiful as C#, but still it is!

Comment: In this case, since SharePoint is really an ASP.Net application, and it already has several ready-made extensibility points that allow you to introduce your own ASP.Net code, I strongly recommend C# (which btw is a way better language) instead of java. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx).

Comment: Agreed! But is it that I can no way deploy a Java based web app on Sharepoint? Sorry if my questions are weird, that's because of lack of knowledge. Pls help me gain some :P